# Deixar o wildfly mais leve para uma aplicação JSF

Tags: java-ee, wildfly

Tenho uma aplicação em produção Java , com CDI, JSF com primefaces e hibernate rodando em um wildfly 10.1.

Essa aplicação esta hospedada no jelastic da localweb.
Porem esta consumindo muita memoria.

Sei que se utilizar um conteiner mais leve como tomcat 8 seria o ideal neste caso. 
E já estamos estudando a possibilidade.

Porem para fins de reduzir custos de forma mais rápida, existe como deixar o wildfly mais leve para esse cenário?